# Creating a form dialogue using SiriKit?

Tags: ios, swift, voice-recognition, siri, sirikit

I'm trying to understand the current limitations of the SiriKit API...I know that lists and notes intents were added.  My question is with the existing API can I have Siri query a user and store the responses as would be done via a typical form?  In other words:

Siri:  What is your name?

User:  Johnny Appleseed

Siri:  Where do you work?

User: Apple

Like this?